# How do I push items with Index to the Vue Js 2 Object?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

All good day to you!

I am having trouble pushing items with an index to an object.
I have a blank object just as below:

```
let data {};
```

I want to push items to the data object as follows:

```
// expected array
data = {
    1000: ['a', 'b'],
    1001: ['x', 'y']
};
```

To achieve that what I tried is:

```
this.$set(data, 1000, ['a', 'b']);
this.$set(data, 1001, ['x', 'y']);
```

I also tried out:

```
data[1000] = ['a', 'b'];
data[1001] = ['x', 'y'];
```

The real problem I am facing is I am getting lots of empty values within the array like this:

[image]

If I print that data object in the HTML then I get something like this:

```
[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ...... ]
```

Since I have a large index value and I am getting a large number of empty values within an array which is slowing down the application and it takes a long time to render in HTML. Can someone help me out here to overcome this issue, please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

An array cannot be used this way. You would have to create a object like that:

```
let data = {
    1000: ['a', 'b'],
    1001: ['x', 'y']
};
```

Afterwards, you can push a new element using your syntax:

```
data[1002] = ['a', 'b'];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me out about creating objects which I already tried out before but I am getting exactly the same issue. Lot's of empty items (null values) out there. And I have updated the question as well.

Comment: Yeah exactly. The array will be initialized with 1000 null values for the first 1000 elements. This is the reason you wouldn't use an array for key-value pairs.

Comment: So, what should I use here? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you do it the way I described it?

Comment: The way you describe does not work as I already told you. It's not about using an array or object. The issue is something else here. Either you use an array or object you still get the same number of null values as Index. Maybe the issue is about __ob__: Observer object which I got in the console. And the issue is it takes a way longer time to render in HTML.